# Find the value of parameter a, so the polynomial has root with multiplicity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

everyone!

Please help me understand what do I have to do here.

I have a function:

$$f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 +3x - 1$$

I need to find possible values of parameter *a*, such that the root of the function has multiplicity.

I have approached this problem like that:

$$f'''(x) = 6 + 2a$$
So I have found that

$$ a = -3$$

Are there any more values of parameters a, that correspond with the requirement above?

Comment: $f'''(x)=6$, not $6+2a$.

Comment: for $a=15/4$ the polynomial factors as $f(x)=\frac{1}{4} (x+2)^2 (4 x-1)$ and has the double solution $x=-2$. For $a=-3$ it is $f(x)=(x-1)^3$. $x=1$ is a triple solution

Comment: @Raffaele thanks! So do I understand correctly, that if the question of the task is to provide the sum of all possible a values, then the answer is -5?

Comment: @Grimmie Well, actually $\frac{15}{4}-3=\frac34$

Comment: @Raffaele you are right! thank you so much!

Comment: I'm unsure what the third derivative has to do with it. Would you mind explaining why you are using it to me?

Answer (score 5):

For a double root, the discriminant
$$\Delta=(a+3)^2 \,(4 a-15)$$ must equal to $0$.

Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

Answer (score 0):

Just experimenting with
$(\pm 1, 1)$ and $(\pm2, 1/4)$ and solving for $\space a,\space $ I found

$$x^3 + ax^2 +3x - 1=(x+2)^2\left(x-\frac14\right)\quad \text{for}\quad a=\frac{15}{4}$$

so the roots are $\bigl(-2,-2,\frac14\big)$

Comment: A quick comment about your LaTeX code: change `\big(` to `\bigl(` in order to avoid making LaTeX/MathJax believe that the `-` symbol in the first instance of  `-2` is a binary operator.

Comment: @ Mico I don't understand. I changed it to \bigl and then to  \left and \right but I see no difference. If I want a dash not to look like a minus, I make sure it is in text mode.

Comment: The issue is not the *length* of the minus symbol, but the *spacing* (or lack thereof) around it. With `$\big( -2,-2\big)$`, there's a noticeable (to me at least) gap between `\big(` and `-` and also between `-` and `2`. That's because the "math status" (TeX jargon alert) of `\big(` is "math-ord" and not "math-open", resulting in `-` being interpreted as a binary rather than as a unary operator. In contrast, the "math status" of `(`, `\bigl(`, and `\left(` is always "math-open"; this lets TeX/MathJax infer (correctly!) that the `-` character should be treated as a unary operator.

Comment: @Mico I tried again and now I see the slight difference in the space in front of the minus sign. It's ridiculous that \big should have any affect on a character other than its size but i understand now that it does.